# Python rounding error for ints in a list (list contains ints and strings)

Tags: python-2.7, rounding-error

I have a python (2.7) script that reads an input file that contains text setup like this:

```
steve 83 67 77
```

The script averages the numbers corresponding to each name and returns a list for each name, that contains the persons name along with the average, for example the return output looks like this:

```
steve 75
```

However, the actual average value for "steve" is "75.66666667".  Because of this, I would like the return value to be 76, not 75 (aka I would like it to round up to the nearest whole integer).  I'm not sure how to get this done...  Here is my code:

```
filename = raw_input('Enter a filename: ')
file=open(filename,"r")
line = file.readline()
students=[] 
while line != "":
    splitedline=line.split(" ")
    average=0
    for i in range(len(splitedline)-1) :
        average+=int(splitedline[i+1])
    average=average/(len(splitedline)-1)
    students.append([splitedline[0],average])
    line = file.readline() 

for v in students:
        print " ".join(map(str, v))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your code is very messy and should be improved overall, the solution to your problem should be simple:

```
average=average/(len(splitedline)-1)
```

should be:

```
average /= float(len(splitedline) - 1)
average = int(round(average))
```

By default in Python 2.x `/` with two integers does **flooring division**. You must explicitly make one of the parameters a floating point number to get real division. Then you must round the result and turn it back into an integer.

In Python 3 flooring division is `//`, and regular division is `/`. You can get this behavior in Python 2 with `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: hmmm..  for some reason this gave me the following output:

     " steve 75.6666666667 " ...  It's showing the precision, but not rounding to the nearest whole integer.  Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: @DtownDom Oh sorry, give me one second.

Comment: Thanks, no rush, i'll be up for awhile :)  Also, sorry for the messy formatting.  This is for an assignment and I generally write messy and clean it up before I submit.  Next time I'll clean up my code before submitting to SO.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!  Sorry I don't have enough rep to vote your answer up, I gotta start doing my part!

I know it's probably taboo to ask a separate question here, but do you know if it would be relatively easy to modify my code to work with a csv version of the input file (ex. " steve,83,67,77 ".  I'm assuming it involves specifying the delimiter to be , instead of whitespace, just not sure how that works yet.

Comment: @DtownDom Use `line.split(",")`, or better (but more complicated for a _beginner_), use the [__`csv`__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. Final two tips: if you're a beginner, stick with Python 3 and read a good book - you'll learn faster with less confusion. Oh and you can accept my answer :)